# Find the number of 4-digit integers whose product of all digits is equal to 16

Tags: permutations, algorithms, combinations

Find the number of 4-digit integers whose product of all digits is equal to 16.

- i approached it as 16 has factor as 1,2,4, and 8.
- so first 4 digit number= 2222 all permutation of it is 1.
- second set is 4411 & it's all permutation equals to 6.
- third set as 8211 & it's all permutation equals to 12.
- so according to me total is 19.

but i'm not getting how my approach is wrong, looking for the kind help if i'm wrong.

Comment: You forgot 4221. Aside from that, your reasoning looks good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to avoid missing or skipping possibilities is to work them in some kind of order.  The largest possible digit involved is $8$, and three other numbers have to multiply to $16$, so $2$ is the highest second number possible, and $8211$ is the only grouping that works with an $8$.

Next try $4$ for the largest value, and the largest value possible remaining is another $4$, giving the $4411$ grouping.  But you can also have $4$ and a $2$, which requires another $2$, and you get $4221$.

Finally if the highest value is $2$, then $2222$ is the only option.

$12+6+12+1 = 31$ ways.